# Zooming Out in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

I want help with my UIScrollView:

I have implemented my UIScrollView in my project and everything works fine but I have problems when Im trying to implement zoom, but this is not as the zoom when we are looking a picture. I am trying to zoom out. My app begins as this graphic when it launches. Lets suppose that I have a UIView in the screen which is bigger than my screen.

```
--------------------------------------------
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|    -----|----------------------|---------|
|    |    |                      |         |<---------UIView
|    |    |                      |<------------------ iPhone Screen frame
|    |    |                      |         |
|    -----|----------------------|---------|
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |<-------- ScrollView Content size
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |<----------------- ScrollView Frame Size
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |      
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         ------------------------         |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
--------------------------------------------
```

And I want my screen look like this when I zoom out.

```
          ------------------------
          |                      |         
          |    ------------------|         
UIView-------->|                 |         
          |    |                 |         
          |    ------------------|
          |                      |         
          |                      |         
          |                      |         
          |                      |
          |                      |         
          |                      |         
          |                      |
          |                      |         
          |                      |               
          |                      |         
          |                      |         
          |                      |         
          ------------------------
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Set the scroll view's `contentOffset` as needed.

Comment: Can you give me an example to understand it better? Im really confused about this topic. If you can use code I would apreciatte it. If not, lets suppose the UIView is 640px * 125px, the Content Size of my UIScrollView is also 640px width and after zooming out the UIView will fit in the screen which is 320px width. How do I set the contentOffset for that case?

Comment: You can zoom out so that the content view is smaller than scroll view by just setting scrollView.minimumZoomScale a small enough number. Do you want to put your content view at a specific position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0 then you can zoom out as much as you want. If you don't want to zoom out too much, give it a reasonable value.